# Configuring Remote Kernel via terminal in Linux

Tags: kernel, remote-access

There's a server at work, which I would like to use as a remote kernel. I have access to it via terminal (server is running Red Hat, my client Windows 7). I don't know if the kernel is set up or not, so I want to check this. However, I don't know how perform this check in the terminal. All [guides](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/ConnectToARemoteKernel.html) I have seen so far require the front end.

So, is there a way to configure a remote kernel via the terminal?

Comment: So you want to run the front end on your own computer, and run a kernel at a remote location?  If yes, you don't need to set up anything on the kernel side.   You need to set up the correct launch command on the front end side, on your computer.  If the server is not directly accessible, you may need to forward some ports through SSH which may be some trouble. (In that case try using the [remote kernel strategies package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226196/firewall-settings-for-remote-kernel-to-work-mathematica#comment7276249_6226196).)

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, that is exactly what I want. I am connected via VPN, I guess that should do it. Why isnt it necessary to config the kernel of the server?

Comment: When the front end launches a kernel, it creates a link, launches the kernel process and passes it command line options which tell it what link to connect to. What you need to do in your case is modify the launching so it happens on the remote machine and modify the link creation so it'll use TCP/IP. It may be sufficient to choose "remote machine" in the kernel configuration options.

Comment: @Szabolcs I tried setting up a new kernel (using Basic Options), where I give server name, login name and command ("math"). When I evaluate an expression I enter my password, but I get the message: `The kernel test failed to connect to the front end. (Error = MLECONNECT). You should try running the kernel connection outside the front end.`. Now sure what to make of this.

Comment: In the past, when I tried to get things like this working, I didn't have a very good experience.  There maybe several things that can go wrong, unfortunately.  Does it prompt from a password when you launch the kernel?  Can you try to set up [passwordless authentication](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.55/htmldoc/Chapter8.html) on the Linux server and try again?  If that doesn't work, then your best (= least-effort) bet might be the Remote Kernel Strategies package I linked to.  It will try to automatically tunnel the necessary ports though SSH, ...

Comment: ... so it won't be a problem if there's a firewall.